# Python Black Jack game variant

Tags: python, while-loop, poker

My Black Jack code is very basic but is running quite smoothly, however I have run into a speed bump. Thus im here. When I call "Hit" to send me another card in my While loop, for every loop the DECK instantiates the same card. The first 2 drawn and the Hit card are always different but within the While loop (which is set to end when the player says "stay" and doesnt want another card.) the Hit cards remain the same.

```
import random
import itertools
SUITS = 'cdhs'
RANKS = '23456789TJQKA'
DECK = tuple(''.join(card) for card in itertools.product(RANKS, SUITS))
hand = random.sample(DECK, 2)
hit = random.sample(DECK, 1)

print("Welcome to Jackpot Guesser! ")
c = input("Would you like to play Black Jack or play Slots? ")
if c == 'Black Jack':
    print()
    print("Welcome to Black Jack! Here are the rules: ")
    print("Black Jack is a game of whit, skill with a bit of Luck. You will start with 2 card and try to achieve a total of 21 points. \n Each cards worth is equal to its number, face cards are worth 10 and the Ace can be 1 or 11 points. You decide. \n You can decide to -Stay- and take the points you have or -Hit- to get another card. If you get 21 its Black Jack and you win. \n If no one gets 21, the highest points win, but if you go over 21 you -Bomb- and lose everything. \n Becarful not to Bomb and goodluck out there! Remember, you got to know when to Hit, when to Stay and when to walk away! \n")
    print(hand)
    print()

    g = 'swag'
    while g != 'Stay':
        g = input(("What would you like to do, Stay or Hit: "))
        if g == 'Hit':
            print(hit)
        elif g == 'Stay':
            print("Lets see how you did!")
        else:
            print("test3")
elif c == 'Slots':
          print("test")
else:
    print("test2")
```

EX: Hand: Td(two diamonds), 3c(3 club)
Hit: 7s(7 spades)
hit 7s
hit 7s
hit 7s
...
stay: lets see how you did. I need the continued While loop Hits to differ, any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are generating the hit card only once, during the start of the program. Changing your code from

```
    if g == 'Hit':
        print(hit)
```

to something like

```
    if g == 'Hit':
        hit = random.sample(DECK, 1)
        print(hit)
```

will make it outputs different cards on each hit.

Comment: Be in mind that this is effectively sampling with replacement, so each card will always have the same chance to be drawn, however many hits you make. This makes card counting impossible. If you want to make a more realistic simulation of blackjack, you can generate a list containing all the cards of N decks, shuffle it (random.shuffle does the trick) and either keep an index on the next card to be drawn, or use pop to remove and get one card from the list.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot! +1

Comment: thanks for suggesting .shuffle(), i wasn't aware of that